# Proof by contradiction of $P\implies Q$?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

If I want to proof the following by contradiction: $$P\implies Q.$$
Say $R$ is a contradiction$(R\equiv\bot)$. By constructing $$\begin{array}{l}
(P\land\lnot Q)\implies R.\\
\lnot R.\\
\hline\therefore\lnot(P\land\lnot Q).\end{array}$$
Since $$\lnot(P\land\lnot Q)\iff\lnot P\lor Q,$$ which implies $$P\implies Q.$$

Is the above correct? Is the above relate to [the Law of Excluded Middle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2145344/390226)?

Comment: Just to clarify your question, $P,Q$ are some propositions that you want to prove the implication for, for some other math problem. You use a somewhat complicated logic, and you want to verify that the logic is sound?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes, I means the logical structure itself and I want to know whether these steps are correct.

Comment: Sure, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your argument looks correct.